# flutter_staggered_grid_view is not getting install in IDE

Tags: dart, gridview, undefined, staggered-gridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAjpq.png)dependencies is also installed.
environment:
sdk: '>=3.2.3 <4.0.0'
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_staggered_grid_view:^0.7.0

But it is showing error
"Undefined name 'StaggeredGridView'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.dartundefined_identifier
Type: InvalidType"

I tried by changing
environment:
sdk: '>=3.2.3 <4.0.0'
to
environment:
sdk: '>=2.19.6 <3.0.0'

EXPECTING :
to remove error from StaggeredGridView error